# Como converter int to QString?

Tags: qt, conversão-de-tipo

Comecei hoje a aprender o toolkit `QT` e na tentativa de executar um pequeno teste deparei-me com uma dúvida: Como converter um inteiro para `QString`?

Existe alguma função que receba um inteiro e retorne um objecto do tipo `QString`?

Comment: Veja [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3211784/2556111)

Comment: Obrigado @ramaral! O seu link me leva para uma resposta igual à que o @bruno já deu. Se  sua sugestão é igual ao dele porque não dar um voto pra ele, já que eu não posso.
Valeu pela força!

Comment: Votei na sua pergunta para o ajudar a obter pontos suficientes para que possa votar em resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado @ramaral, no entanto questiono o porque de não ter votado na resposta. Do pouco tempo que passei no site reparei que as respostas têm muito poucos votos a favor. Este é mais um exemplo de uma boa resposta que não tem votos. O ramaral preferiu apresentar uma resposta exactamente igual à que tinha sido aceito, ao invés de votar.  Não é esse o objectivo da comunidade? Premiar o esforço dos participantes? Caso contrário qual o incentivo para participar?

Comment: Se você reparar na data/hora dos *"postes"*, verificará que o meu comentário foi feito antes da resposta do @bruno. Se a resposta já tivesse sido dada eu não teria colocado o comentário.

Comment: Desculpa, mas o seu comentário for colocado uma hora após a resposta. O que não invalida o facto de não ter votado.

Comment: Tem razão, interpretei mal a data.. A questão é que a sua pergunta, por ser a primeira que fez no site, foi para uma fila de análise onde os usuários mais experientes verificam a conformidade da pergunta. Foi aí que eu vi a pergunta e lá, na fila de análise, não aparecem as respostas dadas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um dos aspectos mais positivos desta framework é a sua extensa documentação. Ainda hoje, tenho sempre a página da [API](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/) aberta para esclarecer as questões mais simples. Recomendo de sobremaneira a sua leitura a quem pretende iniciar o desenvolvimento de software usando este toolkit.

Agora e respondendo à tua pergunta. Para converter um inteiro num objecto do tipo `QString` podes usar o método [QString::number()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number); Este método devolve um objecto do tipo `QString` equivalente ao número e de acordo com a base passados como parâmetro. Por defeito, a base é 10 mas o método aceita valores entre 2 e 36.

```
int i = 42;
QString s = QString::number(i);
```

Outra alternativa é o método [QString::setNum()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#setNum). A diferença para o anterior é que este não
cria um novo object alterando apenas a instância na qual é aplicado. Por exemplo:

```
QString str;
str.setNum(1234);       // str == "1234"
```

Comment: Valeu cara! Ja tinha ouvido falar muito bem desta comunidade. Mas não esperava uma resposta tão rápida e completa. Valeuu!

Comment: Sem problema! Aconselho a ler o tour para perceber melhor como funciona o site e a comunidade. Bem vindo!

Comment: Gostava de poder votar na resposta mas parece que não tenho reputação suficiente. :(